# Radare2 project opening

Tags: radare2

When I open a project `r2 -p mypoject` I get a bunch of errors with some numbers:

```
0
0
Cannot add reference to non-function
Cannot add reference to non-function
1482
```

I use latest version of radare2 from git repository on Arch Linux. This is list of steps to reproduce this bug.

```
r2 /bin/ls
> aaa
> Ps myproject
> q
r2 -p myproject
```

Comment: I have the same. You should file na issue here: https://github.com/radare/radare2/issues

Comment: I opened an issue. Here it is if you're intrested: https://github.com/radare/radare2/issues/8582